# Targeting an element using a selector from another element

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to make set an span to be "display:none" using the [aria-expanded:true] of the proceeding button, but I don't know if I can target the span that way.

I have been trying sibling selectors but I don't understand how to use them.

```
<h2>
<button class="btn btn-primary start" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#projectID" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">TITLE</button></h2>

<div class="projectmargin"><span class="matexcerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>

<div class="collapse" id="project<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <div class="card card-body">
  <span class="matexpanded"><?php the_content(); ?></a>

 </div>
```

What I would like to have happen is when the aria-expanded is "true" that "matexcerpt" is set to display:none, and then when aria-expanded is "false", "matexcerpt" is display:inline.  I would like to do this with CSS if possible. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: See this Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLazgb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `attribute selector` to select `aria-expanded` value and `sibling` selector to select your `matexcerpt` class.

```
button[aria-expanded="true"] + .projectmargin .matexcerpt {
  display: none;
}

button[aria-expanded="false"] + .projectmargin .matexcerpt {
  display: block;
}
```

From the above method, you can do with CSS. You can also do with JavaScript.

That depends on your `aria-expanded` value, if you can change value dynamically by JavaScript, You need to use JavaScript for that but if you have different component for `aria-expanded` values, CSS is the best option.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but it's not working for me on the site... Any thoughts?

Comment: why isn't working, there is no reason of working in that, show your code

Comment: Hi, just to wrap this up, I just got back to this tonight.  This did work, but I have to place the .matexcerpt code right next to the button, like within the same div, rather than the next one over.  But once I rewrote this, it did the trick.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you like it